# How to Change border color of Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

![Bootstrap navbar][1]

Image : URL: http://snag.gy/M6vEI.jpg

Hello, I am learning Bootstrap. And i am trying to make a custom menu using Bootstrap navbar class. Here i am using 3 column. 1 for logo, 2 for navbar, 3 for social icon. And i am using default navbar class for the navbar section. And i am able to change background color of the navbar. But i am unable to change the border of the navbar. Can someone help me ? how to change it?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-background">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header navbar-background">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <!--<span>Menu</span>-->
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-background" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active navbar-background ">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-background">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse --><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with css:

```
.navbar-default { border-color: pink !important; }
```

the `!important` statement might not be necessary, depending on where you put the css rules.

Comment: I would add that for those using the dark menu (navbar-inverse), it would be like this: .navbar-inverse { border-color:red; }, .navbar-inverse {border:none !Important;}, etc.